# How to draw a trapezoid with rounded corners in Adobe XD?

Tags: shapes, drawing, adobe-xd

I want to draw a trapezoid with rounded corners in Adobe XD. I want to give it a blur and design a soft UI (neumorphism) with it.

How can I draw a trapezoid with rounded corners in Adobe XD?

Comment: What I was referring to is the geometric shape. In the meantime, I thought of drawing a triangle and a rectangle, and subtracting the rectangle from the triangle. (I will update the title). Thank you @usr2564301.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe XD is not the best tool when it comes to drawing custom shapes. Once you drag an anchor point from a rectangle you lose the ability to adjust the corner radius.

What you can do is to draw a rectangle, drag the anchors until you get a trapezoid and add a border with the same color as the fill. Set Outer Stroke and Round Join.

You control the corner radius by adjusting the border thickness.

[image: trapezoid]

Comment: What would be the best tool? Something like Adobe Illustrator?

Comment: @Marco if you already have the Adobe package might as well use Illustrator, you have much more control. I just noticed on Figma you can adjust corner radius after altering the rectangle into a trapezoid. It all depends on your needs / skills.

Comment: OK @Luciano, thank you for your helpful answer!